# sklearn: Getting error while importing sklean in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

Importing sklearn gives error in anaconda jupyter notebook. I have installed scikitlearn package and issue is still seen.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "version.py", line 18, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 13
4, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 13, in
 <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", l
ine 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
 line 18, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line
 144, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.
py", line 118, in <module>
    from .matfuncs import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\matfuncs.
py", line 19, in <module>
    import scipy.special
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", l
ine 640, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

(base) C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: post some code also

Comment: I have not written  much, just importing the module.                                                       from sklearn import datasets

Answer (score 0):

As referred in [this link](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5570#issuecomment-161180086) that looks similar. You probably dont have c++ windows compiler. You will need to install Visual C++ Redistributable and then reinstalling anaconda might solve the issue.

On a side note anaconda generally takes care of the installing of the c++ compiler. Did you create virtualenv and pip install. I will suggest you install using conda install.

```
conda install scipy
```